# Specify a language when embedding a Spotify playlist using an iframe

Tags: localization, spotify

Is there a query string parameter (or a special path, or subdomain) that can be used with standard localization codes (e.g. es, nl, de, etc) in conjunction with a url like this `https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:track:4bz7uB4edifWKJXSDxwHcs` that will localize the content from Spotify?

EDIT:
I am referring specifically to the options menu as pictured below as the rest of the text is just artist and track title.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. In this case Spotify doesn't offer any localization codes. But there is no reason for it because it just give you general information title/artist/album etc.

You have to tell us more specific what you want.
If you want to grab data from this url use web-api instead.
https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/web-api/

Use Lookup if you have a special title/artist/album etc. but you need spotify url!
https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/web-api/lookup/

If I would interpret your question in another way:
You can look up 'availability' for certain 'territories'

Just for you to know there is a rate limiting 10 requests per ip/second!

Hope I could helpya! If you need something else or want more help tell us or write me a message ;)

Comment: My use case requires me to embed Spotify playlists via an iframe.  An administrator is able to pick the locale of the site from a CMS.  using that locale, I am able to localize Twitter and Facebook components on the page and i was hoping to also localize the Spotify content in the same manner.  

There is copy in the options menu of the embedded Spotify iframe that i would like to be localized.  I edited my OP to include an image of this menu.